# Cannot open database “Cur” requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'LAPTOP-54F194M9'

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm writing a C# application and need the database to save values. I created a local connection string, but I'm getting the error mentioned in the title on every other system that I'm trying.

Here's the connection string :

```
Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cur;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: As the error suggests, you are not supplying the right authorization credentials to access your database.

Comment: is it your database that name is `Cur` and your user can access to database? run ssms and login to sql with windows authentication.

Comment: "... on every **other** system that I'm trying". So your app works fine on the machine you use to develop but not on any other machine? Did you install sql server on these other machines? Your connection string is set up to use a local express database server with a database named "Cur". If your goal is to have all these other machines use one sql server instance (maybe yours?) in your network, you need to change the connection string.